# Relative strength of 很笨 and it's variants

Tags: slang, topolect

**很笨**

I have heard my doctor refer to his employees on some occasion using the phrase hen ben (I assume he meant 很笨). When I first heard it I was a bit bothered. Should I be upset when this term is used or is this "light teasing"?

I've tried to evaluate this snippet a bit via research and came up with this [discussion](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100722191750AAnVqUP) on Yahoo Answers. A wider [variation](http://www.google.com/custom?domains=www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk&q=stupid&sa=Search&sitesearch=www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk&client=pub-7666422977838952&forid=1&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&cof=GALT%3a#E9382F;GL:1;DIV%3a#CCCCCC;VLC:7E3939;AH%3acenter;BGC%3aFFFFFF;LBGC:991122;ALC%3aE9382F;LC%3aE9382F;T:000000;GFNT:7E3939;GIMP:7E3939;LH:50;LW:292;L%3ahttp://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/images/icons/searchhomeicon.gif;S%3ahttp://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk;FORID:1;&hl=en&channel=6624377293) appears on CantoDict (Cantonese/Mandarin). I guess there are varying degrees of insults and I'm simply curious to what extent this colloquialism applies.

Comment: Wait. You should paste the whole sentence here to provide the context. "ji shi hen ma fan, wo bu yao shi hen ben" 即使很麻烦, (我不要) ...? I'm not definitely sure *hen ben* here is "很笨". Maybe it is just 即使很麻烦，我不要试很笨 **(的方法)**? Please show us where you originally saw the sentence.

Comment: @Stan Sorry for the confusion. This was part of a conversation I overheard where a Dr refers to his staff ...hen ben. As such I only caught the partial phrase related above. The links and references are things I found while researching the origin of the phrase.

Comment: I think this depend really on the context, even on the region (dialect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be upset.

I'd be upset if my employer said I was "很笨".

很笨 pretty much means what you would think it means "very stupid". Teasing on the other hand would be something more along the lines of 傻瓜, etc — and depending on the tone you should be able to tell teasing from non-teasing.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on contexts. "很笨" could be just a mild upset or a teasing that doesn't matter at all. For example, a father could call his kids "很笨" when the kids made mistakes by not following his instructions or advice from a supervising perspective. So is it in the doctor case.